# How to play videos from SD Card

Tags: android, android-videoview

I was creating a simple app which stream videos from net and I made it but now I want to change the code so that I can play video files from my SDCard

original code:

```
Uri vidFile = Uri.parse("MY SITE HERE");
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.start();
```

So please help me with changing the code so that it can play videos from my mobile memory card.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);` method needs to be replaced by the `videoView.setVideoPath(path);` method. 
Here path specifies the path of the video file on the `SDCARD`.

This path can be easily retrieved using the `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA` property of that video file or by just entering the songpath statically as `/sdcard/songname`.

Comment: hey what about Uri vidFile = Uri.parse("MY SITE HERE"); correct me if i am wrong but there is no need of this so i should just delete it?

Comment: btw will it only play .3gp files or it depends on formats supported by my mobile?

Answer (score 6):

```
Uri vidFile = Uri.parse(
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"filename");
...
```

the rest of the code will be same.

Comment: its got a filename for a specific video file, what if i want to select from a list, how to play the SELECTED video file?

Comment: the example code above assumes the file is at the root level.. you can append the /path/filename.mp4 to the path returned by `getabsolutePath()`

Answer (score 1):

In place of

`videoView.setVideoUri(vidFile)`

use

`videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/SONG.")`.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

these links may help you:

[Playing 3gp video in SD card of Android](http://sree.cc/google/android/playing-the-video-in-sd-card-of-android)

[how-play-video-and-audio-android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android)

[Using VideoView to play mp4 from sdcard](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-videoview-to-play-mp4-from-sdcard.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried your code and got same error message but when I tried with video path with no blank space in path or name, it worked well. Just give it a try. 
e.g, 
file path "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/Long Drive Song - Khiladi 786 ft. Akshay Kumar_Asin-YouTube.mp4"
gave the error but file path "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/Khiladi.mp4" worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I know is is old but if it can help. add this to your manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider"/>`