# How to play video on my app with url

Tags: android, android-studio

When I play video using my internal storage it is working fine but when I give  URL this says can't play this video.Please give suggestion. Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Video-demo extends Activity {
      private static final String path ="http://demo.digi-corp.com/S2LWebservice/Resources/SampleVideo.mp4";
      private VideoView video;
        private MediaController ctlr;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

            video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
            video.setVideoPath(path);

            ctlr = new MediaController(this);
            ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
            video.setMediaController(ctlr);
            video.requestFocus();
     }
}
```

Comment: Try `video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));` and move `ctlr = new MediaController(this);` above that.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869830/how-to-play-videos-from-sd-card

Comment: this also says video  can't play

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
String path = "http://demo.digi-corp.com/S2LWebservice/Resources/SampleVideo.mp4";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vv.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {return false;}
});
try {vv.setVideoURI(uri);} catch (Exception e) {}
try {vv.start();} catch (Exception e) {}
vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(null);
    }
});
```

And add these permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: this says the same things can't play this video

Comment: Have you checked the url?